# JSON array not printing keys

Tags: php, mysql, json

Grabbing an JSON array from a query.  It's not printing the keyss with in the data.

What I expect:

```
["0":"3675E5010E2738","1":"4114009","2":"2012-11-05","3":"Active","4":"2012-12-11"]
```

What I get...

```
["3675E5010E2738","4114009","2012-11-05","Active","2012-12-11"]
```

JSON is produced from PHP/JSON encode:

```
$array = $model->ListData();
echo json_encode($array);
```

I've tried loading both `loadRowList();` and `loadAssocList();` and neither produce the keys.

Comment: What you expect is not JSON, also what does `var_dump($array);` give you?

Comment: Weird as most examples I've seen as JSON have the keys associated with the data.  Oh well.  Guess I'll just have to use numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's not how JSON represents arrays

`["0":"3675E5010E2738","1":"4114009","2":"2012-11-05","3":"Active","4":"2012-12-11"]` is not valid JSON.

`{"0":"3675E5010E2738","1":"4114009","2":"2012-11-05","3":"Active","4":"2012-12-11"}` is, but that's the representation of an object, not an array.

If `$model->ListData();` returns an array, as your code suggests that it does, then the representation that you're getting is correct.

Anyway, since `json[0]` would work the same way, regardless of whether it was an array or an object with numerical keys, what does it matter?

Comment: First time using JSON.  Did not know that.  Used numerical keys in PHP, got confusing after a while.  I was hoping to use assoc arrays with JSON.

Comment: so, getting the data from JSON/AJAX would go like: 

 `$.ajax({
        url: url,
        datatype: JSON,
        success: function(data){
            $('#test').html(data.0);
        } });`

Answer (score 1):

You have numerical keys which are in order starting from 0. You don't need to have the keys present for it to be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that JSON is javascript object notation, this means that it uses javascript syntax.

var myObject = {
    0: 'zero',
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two'
};
var myArray = [
    'zero',
    'one',
    'two'
];

Arrays and Objects are used for different purposes. Objects supports keys, arrays do not.